# Embedded resource and adding images

Tags: image, forms, resources, gtk

I am developing a form application with monodevelop. I'm using gtk#.

I need to add an image to a widget in the form. I am also trying to make this image an embedded resource as well, before including it in the form.

so far this is what I have:

```
HBox CharacterPic = new HBox();
Image LegionnairePic = new Image('somehow load the embedded resource image here');
CharacterPic.PackStart (LegionnairePic);
```

In the 'Solution' section to the left, I have added .jpeg files and changed their 'build action' to 'embedded resource'. However, I cannot access/load them onto the form them as so:

```
Image LegionnairePic = new Image(<namespace>.<resource>);
```

How do I add the image resource to the form? Am I even adding the resource correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to access the embedded files with the following method:

```
// string resource_id is the Resource ID of the file in the sidebar “Properties”
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource_id);
```

This returns the resource file as a Stream.

If this helped, thank [that](http://www.joebest.org/2011/09/monodevelop-and-loading-embedded.html) guy like I did :)